# Visual C# - Changing button's background image programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm trying to make a simple program in Visual C# that counts the number of "Connected Devices", which can be seen as the amount of buttons clicked.

The code should check which button was clicked and change it's background image. It should also update the count and label on the form.

First of all, here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Device_Storage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int totalDevices = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void addDevice(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Button clickedBtn = sender as Button;
                Image add_image = Properties.Resources.addDevice;
                Image remove_image = Properties.Resources.removeDevice;

                if (clickedBtn.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.addDevice)
                {
                    clickedBtn.BackgroundImage = remove_image;
                    totalDevices++;
                }
                else if (clickedBtn.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.removeDevice)
                {
                    clickedBtn.BackgroundImage = add_image;
                    totalDevices--;
                }

                updateLabel();
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "An Error Occured");
            }

        }

        private void updateLabel()
        {
            label1.Text = "Connected devices: " + totalDevices;
        }
    }
}
```

(I didn't change any of the using statements yet, I usually do that when I'm finished or am 100% sure I won't be using the namespace)
I can't find anything wrong with the code myself and Visual Studio (2015) doesn't give an error.
When I click a button (there are 36 total buttons) nothing happens, the label doesn't update, the image doesn't change, nothing. I don't even get an error, the program doesn't crash.

If anyone can see what I did wrong and can help me fix it that would be really appreciated.

(Edit: My resources folder contains 2 png files, "addDevice.png" and "removeDevice.png")

(New info: all buttons start with the background image "addDevice.png" as to represent an empty slot)

Comment: Did you debug the form? Set a breakpoint inside the method to see if it is even being hit, maybe you forgot to bind the event handler to the forms event.

Comment: @DF1229 Do all buttons start with a background image?

Comment: @Sorceri Yes they do, they all start with the image "addDevice.png", to represent an empty slot.

Comment: @Kolichikov 
 
I did, when any of the buttons are clicked they all trigger the method "addDevice". When I tried it earlier when I didn't try to change the background image it worked fine for all the buttons.

Comment: Did you actually check the breakpoint?  Sounds like your if conditions are never being met, which would be why nothing is happening.

Comment: well the label doesn't update most likely because you are using devices and I am going to assume you mean to use totalDevices

Comment: You might want to have your ifs check for a property on the images, in case the references aren't the same.  So maybe set the Tag property on each image and then compare those to make sure they are equal to your values and execute your logic.

Comment: @Lunyx Yes I did, everytime I click one of the button the program breaks at the if statement without giving errors. When I continue and click another button it does the same thing.

Comment: @Sorceri Yeah that's my bad, forgot to change it here, already changed it in my code, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @DF1229  The resource is a bitmap the background is an image. Change your checks to clickedBtn.BackgroundImage == add_image and remove_image

Comment: Breaking at the if statement doesn't indicate that the code within the block will be executed.  Have you stepped through to check if the code within the if block itself is executed?

Comment: @Kolichikov I'm not sure what you mean, I haven't been using visual studio for a very long time, only about 4-5 months now, and I haven't gone really in depth with it. What I make up from your message is to check if the images are in the folder they should be in. (Which they are)

Comment: @Lunyx Yes I have, and it did get executed without any errors.

Comment: Try calling `clickedBtn.Refresh()`

Comment: @Lunyx Just to be sure, do you mean before or after the if statement?

Comment: After you set the background image.

Comment: @Lunyx No change in results. However I might have found what I did wrong, when I put a breakpoint on the if statement it does get run, however when I put one on the code that should get run when the button is clicked it doesn't get run.

Comment: Images don't have a way to check for equality, so you will have to use some other method, like a Dictionary or the button's Tag property to store "key" information.

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/domgreen/2009/09/06/comparing-two-images-in-c/

Comment: I would suggest reading up on how to use the debugger more efficiently because it sounds like you're not really sure what you're doing. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn